# VB6 lost F1 help function after Install of VS2005, re-install of MSDN2001 did not work

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, msdn

After installing VS2005 VB6 lost F1 function to MSDN Oct/2001 lib.

Suggestions to re-install MSDN did not work.

The only thing F1 works on now are ADO statements in VB6. Example ado1.recordset.recordcount  If I highlight recordcount and press F1 I do get the ADO help information. If I highlight "recordset", I get "Help not found" dialog.

Same with say any regular VB tools property. lblEvent.Caption  Get error trying to find help on say caption. If I highlight say Next in a for next loop I get a dialog that wants to know ... Multiple instances of the selected word have been found. Please select a topic and press Help.  In this case VBA is one, Excel is one  MSComctlLib is one. If I highlight FOR in a statement I get the "Help Not Found" error again.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once.  The only thing I could do to fix it was a complete re-install of VB6 (wasn't caused by installing VS2005, but installing a component that added its own doc to Help).  Probably not what you want to hear.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after a Windows Update, or maybe it was one of the XP service packs. Un-installing hotfix 896358 solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me, trying to compile a vb6 dll wasn't working.
Turns out that an update had been installed in the background and i needed to reboot before it would allow me to compile it again.